# Can I use my German T-mobile Prepaid Xtra Tripple card in Austria?

Tags: germany, cellphones, international-travel, austria

I have a prepaid Xtra Triple card with T-Mobile. I'll be doing some traveling to Austria in the next week, is there anyway to use my data while I'm there without being charged .50 per mb?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [DayPass M](http://www.t-mobile.de/roaming/0,25096,25649-_,00.html#seite=1&reiter=2) which includes 50 MB for one day and costs 2.95 EUR. It's the only roaming data package for T-Mobile prepaid cards that you can use in Austria.